# Use Custom DTOs in WCF RIA in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, wcf-ria-services, visual-studio-lightswitch

Need help with converting my VB.NET DTOs so that they can be used by WCF RIA for a LightSwitch application.

I found a great example here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2009/07/16/business-apps-example-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update-part-6-data-transfer-objects-dtos.aspx

My question that I have failed to find an answer for is how do I represent the syntax marked in the square brackets in the C# code in VB.NET?

```
public class SuperEmployeeDTO{

public SuperEmployeeDTO()        
{        
}  

[ReadOnly(true)]        
[Key]        
public int EmployeeID {get;set;}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<[ReadOnly](True)>
<Key()>
Public Property EmployeeID() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_EmployeeID
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        m_EmployeeID = value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_EmployeeID As Integer
```

Comment: 'Imports System.ComponentModel' lets the '<[ReadOnly](True)> _' be but it still isn't liking '<Key()> _' above my key property.  Anything I should be importing for that?  Thanks @Robbie Tapping

Comment: That was something I tried.  "Type Key is not defined" is my error.

Comment: is the Key type a Property type for RIA Services, or is this an attribute you actually create yourself in your RIA Model Service?

Comment: To be honest i have never seen the [Key] Attribute used before, in your c# example what is its context?

Comment: I believe it is a way to expose the class' key property to the WCF RIA "Domain Service".  Perhaps it isn't necissary for VB.NET? I'll have a play.  Thanks for your help